How to Automate Code Generation for Generating Access Token Using Refresh Token
I was Generating Access Token from Salesforce Using Refresh Token in Postman. Where i have used Params in Postman.
<BaseUrl>/services/oauth2/token? Code = <Generated Code> grant_type = authorization_code Client_id = xyz Client_secret = xyz redirect_uri = https://login.salesforce.com
in this params i have to generate Code every time  by simply  copy pasting the URL in Url Section and in Chrome and hit Enter
URL = <BaseURL>/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xyz&redirect_uri=https://login.salesforce.com
How to Automate The Code Generation so we Can Generate Access Token Every time without Generating Code Every time.
Yet i'm not able to Think for Solution
